# Absolutely continuous functions on all closed subintervals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Question: Prove or disprove the following.

Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and bounded variation. If $f$ is absolutely continuous on all closed subintervals $[c,d] \subset (0,1)$ then $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[0,1]$.

My attempt: I believe this statement is true as an equivalent definition of absolutely continuous function defined on a bounded interval is that $f$ is continuous, bounded variation and maps sets of measure zero to sets of measure zero (Lusin-N property). How do you use the Lusin-N property to show such function is absolutely continuous? Or if otherwise, is there a well-known counterexample?